# How do I draw two half circles on this image?

Tags: c, for-loop, ppm

Here's my image:

[image]

I've already written code that will give me a ppm file with the horizontal white and red bars. But what I'm having trouble with is, how do I draw those two half circles? It is IDEAL to use nothing more complicated than for loops/if statements to do this. I'm given this information:

[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("P6\n");
   printf("%d %d\n", 600, 400);
   printf("255\n");

   int col, row;
   unsigned char Rcolor, Bcolor, Gcolor;

   for (row = 1; row <= 200; row++) {
      for (col = 1; col <= 600; col++) {
         Rcolor = 255;
         Gcolor = 255;
         Bcolor = 255;

         printf("%c%c%c", Rcolor, Gcolor, Bcolor);
      }
   }

   for (row = 201; row <= 400; row++) {
      for (col = 1; col <= 600; col++) {
         Rcolor = 255;
         Gcolor = 0;
         Bcolor = 0;

         printf("%c%c%c", Rcolor, Gcolor, Bcolor);
      }
   }

   return (0);
}
```

Any help/advice is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: The equation of a circle is `x * x + y * y = r * r`. Apart from that, those `%c%c%c` conversion specifiers ought to be `%d %d %d` (if this really is in the PPM format...)

Comment: H2CO3: Alright! Thanks. One thing though, I'm using columns and rows instead of x and y so if I were to use the "x * x + y * y etc..", would I have columns instead of x and rows instead of y? (And the radius would just be the radius given to me correct?)

Comment: claptrap: I was thinking about using cos and sin, but I don't have an angle to work with :(

Comment: @Karen It precisely doesn't matter since the X and Y dimensions of the circle are equal. You would only have to worry about flipping dimensions if you drew an ellipse. And yes, `r` is just the specified radius.

Comment: H2CO3: So I'm not sure if I'm right but, using that equation, the point (x, y) would then have to be less than or equal to the radius squared right? In order for it to be a point on/in the circle?